# Does anyone know which TextMate theme Michael Hartl uses in his Ruby on Rails Tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As the title says... Does anyone know which TextMate theme Michael Hartl uses in his Ruby on Rails Tutorial? I googled for it but can't see that the question has been asked before.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com) theme, found here: http://railscasts.com/about

Comment: Thanks. That looks like it. Good to see it's included in the Gmate plugin for gedit as well!

Comment: Yup, that's the one I use. I'm considering using Sublime Text for the next edition of the screencasts, and happily it can use TextMate themes as well, so the look should be familiar. Unlike TextMate, though, it supports split panes and is cross-platform. Given the audience, the latter in an especially big advantage.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/) theme, could be downloaded [here](http://railscasts.com/about)

cheers